# How do I know when to release an NSDate object?

Tags: iphone, release, nsdate

Do either or both of these date pointers requires a [release] when I'm done with them. How would i know this? I'm unsure since I'm not doing init explicitly.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSDate *date = [dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:100000000];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are autoreleased, that is you don't need to release them yourself. The rule of thumb is that you own an object if you send +alloc or -copy or explicitly retain it:

- [[SomeClass alloc] init...]
- [someObject copy]
- [some object retain]

If you own an object you must release it. +new is a shortcut to +alloc and -init.

Comment: Ok, but is it incorrect to release it?  When will it get released if I do not do so explicitly?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong to release an object you don't own. This is called "over-releasing" and will cause a crash when -release (or any other message, for that matter) is sent to an already-released object. Autoreleased objects are actually released when the enclosing NSAutoreleasePool is released/drained (if you don't use them explicitly, this happens at the end of each cycle of the event loop). See "Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa".

Answer (score 5):

No, both of the returned dates from those methods are autoreleased. You don't need to worry about their memory management, though to be a good citizen, setting the pointer to nil when you're done with them would be a good idea.

As a general rule, you can follow what I call the "CARN" rule. in Cocoa/Cocoa Touch any method that has the words *Copy, Alloc, Retain,* or *New* in them will return objects that need to be released by you at some point. These are naming conventions applied to methods that return objects with a retain count of +1. The class that calls these methods "owns" the object and is responsible for releasing it when it's finished with it.

Hope this helps.